croppie.js cambiar tamaño de slider y la imagen
Estoy utilizando croppie.js y todo bien, pero cuando subo la imagen, me la carga enorme, al tamaño real.
Vi que en sus ejemplos en la web oficial sí se ajusta, pero no sé qué estoy poniendo mal en mi proyecto que no se ajusta, solo me sale gigante y el scroll hace zoom infinito.
Ya probé con varias configuraciones como en la documentación pero nada
Este es mi código
      function dUpload() {

    var $uploadCrop;

    function readFile(input) {
        const archivo = input.files[0];
 
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('.upload-demo').addClass('ready');
                    $uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
                        url: e.target.result
                    }).then(function(){
                        console.log('jQuery bind complete');
                        //ocultar foto - mostrar crippie
                        $('#upload_main_container').show();
                        $('#photo_main_container').hide();                           
                    });
                    
                }
                
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
            else {
                swal("Sorry - Solo puedes seleccionar imagenes");
            }
    }

   
    $uploadCrop = $('#upload-demo').croppie({
          enableExif: true,
          viewport: {
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              type: 'circle'
            },
            boundary: {
                width: 300,
                height: 300
            }
          
    });

    $('#upload').on('change', function () { readFile(this); });
    $('.upload-result').on('click', function (ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();

        $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
            type: 'canvas',
            size: 'viewport',
             
        }).then(function (resp) {
             
             $('#layerLoading').show();
             var v_url= "{{ path('saveImg') }}";
             
              //alert("guarda en servidor ");


        });
    });
} 

De antemano muchas gracias
